Maintaing relation
Assalam o alaikum. I have an elder sister and her behaviour is extremely rude towards me despite the best of my efforts. The thing usually starts when I request her to talk in a slow voice and modest manner because the neighbours can hear her. But, she never cares what I say and then starts using bad words. A few days ago, she even said that I can swear upon this that I extremely hate you. She also said that I only use you when I want to get some favour from you. Apart from this, you're nothing for me.
Till date, I have tried my best to keep my relation intact with her but I can't bear now. This has become a daily routine. I have decided to stop talking with her so that she can realize.
Kindly guide on this matter

Abandoning is haram either black or white just one thing occur to my mind when you say should I not talk to her if even if she hates you no matter what you should be nice to her even if she is not nice to you abonnning your siblings for more than 3 days will make you suffer in jahanum for years i hope you dont want that may Allah guide each one of us towards the right path

This answer does not seem very well thought out nor has any sources or proof. It is quiet vague and could help with some changes
